# Extjs Component Ext.ComponentQuery.query access component by a variable name

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs Ext.ComponentQuery.query as below to access a component named combo_box_2.

```
var i = 2;
var name2 = "combo_box_" + i;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combo[name=combo_box_2]')[0].bindStore(error_store);
```

The above code works fine. But I need to access the component by giving variable name name2 as below instead of giving the name straight away. But it does not work. Can anyone help me with this.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combo[name=name2]')[0].bindStore(error_store);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to concatenate the string with the variable part in order to have the name be part of the query.

```
var i = 2;
var name2 = "combo_box_" + i;
var query = 'combo[name=' + name2 + ']';
Ext.ComponentQuery.query(query)[0].bindStore(error_store);
```

You could also use the new ES6 feature [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) to archive it.

```
var i = 2;
var name2 = "combo_box_" + i;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query(`combo[name=${name2}]`)[0].bindStore(error_store);
```

Comment: This is a useful answer